# When is $1^n+2^n+3^n+4^n+\cdots+n^n$ a square number?

Tags: nt.number-theory

I've been thinking about such an interesting question these last few days. I wonder if anyone has studied it.

> **Question:**  Find all postive integers $n$ such that
>   $$S(n)=1^n+2^n+3^n+4^n+\cdots+n^n$$ is a square number?

Here $n=1$ is clear and if $n=3$ then $S(3)=36=6^2$. Now I can't find any other $n\le 20$, so I conjecture these $n$ are the only two values.

Comment: What have you done so far? Did you predict how often this should happen based on asymptotics? Check for obstructions (mod n)?  Plug the sequence into OEIS?

Comment: If $n=2^k s$ and $k>0$ is even, then $S(n)$ is divisible by $2^{k-1}$, but not by $2^k$, thus can not be a perfect square. Analogously, if $n=4k+2$, then $S(n)$ is congruent to $n/2=2k+1$ modulo 8, thus $k$ must be divisible by 4.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A031971 (obtained plugging 4 terms 1, 5, 36, 354)

Comment: I checked all $n \leq 4000$, and there were no new examples.

Comment: tested up to $n\le 5500$.

Comment: If $p>2$ is a prime then $a^p+(p-a)^p \equiv p^2 (\textrm{mod } p^3)$ so that $S(p) \equiv p^2(p-1)/2 (\textrm{mod } p^3)$. Now $(p-1)/2$ is a square mod $p$ if and only if $4(p-1)/2=2p-2=-2$ is a square mod $p$, which is equivalent to $p \equiv 1,2,3$ mod 8. So if $p \equiv 5,6,7$ mod 8 then $S(p)$ is not a square.

Comment: For fun: tested up to $n\le 10000$.

Comment: By computing $S(n)$ efficiently mod $p$ for small $p$, I have verified that $S(n)$ is not a square for $4 \leq n \leq 10^{7}$. The most difficult $n$ was $n = 9676659$ for which $S(n)$ is a square mod $p$ for $3 \leq p \leq 149$.

Answer (score 21):

This is not an answer, but I don't have enough reputation to comment. For large $n$, $S(n)\approx n^n.$ The density of square integers at $n^n$ is approximately $n^{-n/2}$. So one might expect that the number of $S(n)$ which are square is about $\sum_{\mathbb N} n^{-n/2} \approx 1.7788$.

Comment: I believe $S(n)$ is better approximated by $\frac{e}{e-1}n^n$, but up to a constant the order of magnitude is right.

Comment: And given that the OP checked up to $n=20$ and the fact that $\sum_{n\ge21} n^{-n/2}\approx 1.5\cdot 10^{-14}$, the chances of there being any other examples is vanishingly small.

Comment: Denoting by  $ C=\dfrac{e}{e-1} $, one has  $C^{-1}(\sum_{n>0}n^{-n/2})^{2}\approx 2 $ . Is there a reason for this ?

Comment: (Technical comment to take new developments into account: two commenters at 2018-03-07 14:52:58Z and 2018-03-07 16:30:52Z not only "checked up to $n=20$ but up to $n=5500$, and still did not find another example.)

Comment: (but the argument also applies to the sequence $S_0(n){\bf =}n^n$, which is nevertheless a square more than half of the time).

Comment: Of course such probabilistic reasoning is only suggestive. I think of this in the framework of Bayesian statistics. If one has a "prior" view that there might be something there, for some heuristic reason or intuition, or whatever - then the probabilistic argument should be given less weight. However, given no reasons to believe that $S(n)=n^2$ should be true for unseen $n$, I'd give decent weight to the probabilistic argument. I can see no reason why it might be true, but it may be very well be a lack of insight on my part.

Answer (score 9):

An easy obstruction (mod 8). We can exclude all odd multiples of $4$, because for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $S(8k+4)=2\mod 4.$  (Reason: if $j$ is even, $j^{8k+4}=0\mod 4$, and  if $j$ is odd, $j^{8k+4}=1\mod 4$, and there are $4k+2$ odd numbers from $1$ to $8k+4$).

Comment: You can also exclude those values which lead mod 8 to anything other than 0,1, or  4.  This takes out a few more numbers mod 16.  Gerhard "Then Try Mod Three Next" Paseman, 2018.03.05.

Comment: Exact, indeed $S(8k+6)=3\mod 4$ for all $k$, by a similar computation.

Comment: "Then Try Mod Three Next" :  this takes out 3 numbers mod 18.
In fact, for any prime $p$, $S(n)\mod p$ is periodic with period $(p-1)p^2$. For p=5, this takes out 15 numbers mod 100. (Not sure if this way one can exhaust all n though)

Comment: @PietroMajer At least checking finitely many congruences will still fail to exclude at least one arithmetic progression. Indeed it's enough with a single congruence modulo $m$, and given $m$, we see that $S(n)$ is 0 modulo $m$ for every $n$ multiple of $m!$.

Comment: (more in general, for any given positive integer $m$, the sequence $S(n) \mod m$ is periodic with period $\varphi(m)m^2$)

Comment: @PietroMajer no, only *eventually* periodic. For instance $\varphi(8)8^2=256$, but modulo 8 we have $S(2)\equiv 5$ while $S(258)\equiv 1$.

Comment: We may exclude also odd multiples of $4^m$, see my comment to the question

Answer (score 1):

A special case,

**Thm 1**:    if prime $\ p\equiv 3\ $ mod $4,\ $ then
$\ 1^{p-1}+\ldots (p-1)^{p-1}\ $ is not a square.

---

Answer (score 0):

Not a real answer either, but this link may be relevant : [Faulhaber's formula](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula)

In particular one could try to establish, following Pietro Majer and Gerhard Paseman, that a solution of the diophantine equation  $ S(n)=m^{2} =P_{n}(a)$ only occurs for odd values of  $ n $, where  $ a=n(n+1)/2 $ and  $ P_{n} $ is the  $ n $-th Faulhaber polynomial.